# dynamic uitableviewcell height according to custom cell height

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am wondering, is there a way to read the height of the custom tableview cell you are going to use in your uitableviewcell which you can then say to your uitableviewcell be this ---> height?

Answer (score 2):

I am not fully understand your question but do you want to set the height for each custom cell ? If yes then you can do it by :

Let say I have custom cell at index 0 rest are my default cells or can be custom cell as well .

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0 ) {
       return 105.0;
    }else {
        return 80.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, thats pretty much what I was thinking. However in this case I will have to declare in advance a lost of heights as I plan to have several different sized cells. to be fair this is not very dynamic. I was hoping that I would be able to check the height of the custom cell and then just use that as the value for the height.

Comment: Unfortunately,it isn't accessible.  It seems very odd that Apple put that option in there but it doesn't transfer over to code.

Comment: While not convenient, this is perfectly 'dynamic', and can be used to achieve what you want. The implementation will vary depending on how you determine your cell height, but just translate that into code and put it in this method. If the height is based solely on the class of the cell, then query the class using isKindOfClass and return the appropriate result.

Answer (score 0):

No, the height that you set in the xib/storyboard is for **display purposes only** and doesn't transfer over to code.

The only way to change the height is from your custom subclass, by overriding `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If you have a lot of different heights, you could always subclass UITableViewCell and add a `height` property which `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` uses when it sees your subclass.  Then, in your storyboard, select your cell, go to the identity inspector, and add a **User Defined Runtime Attribute** for height with the value that you need.